# Count more values at the time mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

How can I count more values at the time?
My collection looks like this, and I want to count the fields `msg` and `severity`

```
[
  {
    "msg": "A",
    "severity": "hello1",
    "group": "bb"
  },
  {
    "msg": "B",
    "severity": "hello1",
    "group": "bb"
  },
  {
    "msg": "A",
    "severity": "hello2",
    "group": "bb"
  },
  {
    "msg": "C",
    "severity": "hello2",
    "group": "bb"
  }
]
```

The result I want to get is something like this:

```
[
    [{
        "_id" : "A",
        "count" : 2.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : "B",
        "count" : 1.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : "C",
        "count" : 1.0
    }],
    [{
        "_id" : "hello1",
        "count" : 2.0
    },
    {
        "_id" : "hello2",
        "count" : 2.0
    }],
]
```

And the code I've tried is:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate({
    $and: [
    {
        [
            { $unwind: "$msg" },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {$toLower: '$msg'},
                    count: { $sum: 1 }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        [
            { $unwind: "$severity" },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {$toLower: '$severity'},
                    count: { $sum: 1 },
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}).toArray();
```

But I get this error:

> Error: Line 5: Unexpected token ,

This code started from:

```
db.getCollection('events').aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$msg" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {$toLower: '$msg'},
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]).toArray();
```

And it works properly (just for `msg` field); I just tried to combine 2 `$unwind` and 2 `$group`

[Here is a snippet](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Aw1WUn28v3M)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can execute parallel pipelines on a data set using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/).

**The following query can get us the expected output:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $facet:{
            "messagesInfo":[
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":{
                            $toLower:"$msg"
                        },
                        "msg":{
                            $first:"$msg"
                        },
                        "count":{
                            $sum:1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project:{
                        "_id":0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "severityInfo":[
                {
                    $group:{
                        "_id":{
                            $toLower:"$severity"
                        },
                        "severity":{
                            $first:"$severity"
                        },
                        "count":{
                            $sum:1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project:{
                        "_id":0
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8bb2751b53cab235fc20e0"),
    "msg" : "A",
    "severity" : "hello1",
    "group" : "bb"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8bb2751b53cab235fc20e1"),
    "msg" : "B",
    "severity" : "hello1",
    "group" : "bb"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8bb2751b53cab235fc20e2"),
    "msg" : "A",
    "severity" : "hello2",
    "group" : "bb"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d8bb2751b53cab235fc20e3"),
    "msg" : "C",
    "severity" : "hello2",
    "group" : "bb"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "messagesInfo" : [
        {
            "msg" : "C",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "msg" : "B",
            "count" : 1
        },
        {
            "msg" : "A",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ],
    "severityInfo" : [
        {
            "severity" : "hello2",
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "severity" : "hello1",
            "count" : 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know about `$facet`, you saved me